# Stop AppDelegate from loading ViewController while calling another method

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate

I updated the storage methodes of my app from a simple write to file to CoreData. To save all data from previous version I wrote an migration method which the app delegate calls in

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self checkForPreCoreDataFilesAndMigrate];
    //normal launching 
}
```

The `checkForPreCoreDataFilesAndMigrate` method migrates all files from previous version in the CoreData Database.

My Problem now is that I want to stop the appdelegate from doing other thing like loading the Main ViewController with an empty database(which basically works but messes up the migration process).

How can I achieve this? Is there a solution where I still can show an `UIAlterView` with `UIProgressView` which were set up by the migration method.

Comment: Are you doing something asynchronous in checkForPre...? Execution should proceed only after returning from that method so I'm confused about your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following method for it

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkForPreCoreDataFilesAndMigrate) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```